# Sencha Touch - Registering with ID issue

Tags: javascript, dom, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am specifying an `id` property to `'Ext.Container'`.

**I want to reuse this container in different files. I want to get the childs of this container in multiple files.**
 But, since I specified an `id` for it, it gives me an error when I try to access it beyond first time ..

> [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id
>   (`gBlock1`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing
>   component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.

My code snippet ..

```
Ext.define('ABC.view.XYZ', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    id: 'gBlock1',
    xtype: ...
    ......
```

I was using `id` property because I wanted to access all of Container's button in one go like this,

```
var buttons = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gBlock1 button');
```

and use it later as `buttons[0]`,`buttons[1]` etc ...

What should I do ? How to use `itemsId` as an alternative for it on `Ext.Container`

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a special config in Sencha Touch and designed to be unique per component type, so do not try to use it multiple times.

In your case, there's a much more simple solution:

- define some custom config, say:

  `type: 'SpecialType';`
- query it later using:

  `var buttons = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[type="SpecialType"]');`

Comment: I don't see any property `type` for either Component, Container or button in Sencha Docs  .. Where should I specify this type:'SpecialType' ?

Comment: Where to define that custom config property ?

Comment: FYI, I am opening this view container multiple times within my application. So, I want it to behave same everytime I open it .. What should I do ?

Comment: just like you define `id` or any other config

Comment: Now, it works correctly as you said. I have a stopwatch in this container view along with all buttons.  I have defined this `type` property on container. But, when I am re-opening this container, error is gone .. but the stop watch doesn't work properly. It only works properly the first time ..

Comment: `initialize()` runs when your component is initialized, i.e. the first time it's created. What you want to do, (might be) `show` event

Comment: when i try to listen for show event, i get a blank screen. None of my component can be seen ... :(

Comment: I have a back button in this container's titlebar. How I can destroy this container on back button click with `id:gBlock` so that whenever i re-open this container view .. i don't have any problem with id ..

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure since currently i have no imagination of your application :(

Comment: Basically, I am using back button - so, I need to open this view multiple times .. how about going for it ?

Comment: In which event do you destroy this container ? Container's `erased()` event or `hide()` event ?

Comment: One simple question - How and when would you destroy the Container with `id:gBlock` and then re-open the same container so that same id issue doesn't come up ...

Comment: please avoid extended chatting here, if you have irrelevant question to the current situation, please raise new questions